# UIImageView Aspect to Fit not working when tableview scrolls

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I use the code below to scale images to my UIImageView. Everything is fine when the table loads first time. But when I scroll the tableview, all the image aspects became broken.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ProductCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [self configureCustomCell:(ProductsTableViewCell*)cell atIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;
}

- (void)configureCustomCell:(ProductsTableViewCell*)cell atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[[arr_products objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] productImage]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    __weak UITableViewCell *weakCell = cell;

    [cell.productPhotoImage setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil
          success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {
                weakCell.imageView.image = image;
              weakCell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
              weakCell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
              weakCell.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5, 5, 60, 60);
          }
    failure:nil];
}
```

Comment: Please show your code in `- tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: @serdar aylanc are u using custom cell??

Comment: @satheesh I updated the code in the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the image from the  server and then load it on the cell tableviewcell won't upgrade properly,

you can use SDWebImage Library to load the image from server, Check this link [SDWEbImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

If you want to add activity indicator check this https://github.com/JJSaccolo/UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage

```
#import <SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h>
```

in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
[weakCell.myImage setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrl] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"mawgif-log.png"] options:SDWebImageRefreshCached usingActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
```